# Rails to PHP - How to determine a logged in user

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have a rails app on a domain of `example.com` This domain runs a rails app that when you log in, would share your cookie and the apps secret key with a sub domains rails app allowing you to log in once in one place and be logged in, in another place.

Awesome

Because rails generates secure cookies, how do I share the rails apps secret key and the cookie generated when you log in with the php app on another subdomain?

The goal is to do the same thing I would do with two rails apps but this time from rails to a php app. Google has come up with nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it session cookie or have specific name?

Comment: Im sorry what? @frz3993